# How do you do a simple XY Box Style zoom in Dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

All the Zoom interactions in Dygraph are either horizontal or vertical (Covering the whole width or length). I want to make a traditional box-style zooming.

http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/interaction